# Antenna connector name

Tags: connectors

What is the name of this antenna connector on the Kenwood TH-F6A?

[image: antenna connector]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a standard female SMA connector.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is a standard Female SMA connector.  Heads-up to be careful when purchasing SMA antennas as there are several combinations.  Most higher-end HTs have a standard Female SMA connector on the radio, and a standard Male SMA on the antenna.  Many of the newer Chinese-made HTs invert that, with the standard Male SMA on the radio, and a standard Female SMA connector on the antenna.  Meanwhile, most WiFi equipment uses "Reverse Polarity SMA" (RP-SMA), where the threads are the same as the standard male & female, but the pin and receptacle are swapped:

- Standard SMA Female = center receptacle & external thread
- Standard SMA Male = center pin & internal thread
- RP-SMA Female = center pin & external thread
- RP-SMA Male = center receptacle & internal thread

See the wikipedia article for details and images:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA_connector

I had previously written here, incorrectly, that the Chinese HTs have RP-SMA connectors, which is apparently a common mis-conception among Hams (myself included).  Thanks to MoTLD for the correction.

Comment: While it's good to mention RP-SMA vs. standard SMA, in my experience RP-SMA are only found on WiFi stuff, not Chinese radios. The confusion is in that in the pre-Chinese-HT era pretty much everybody had standardized on the female SMA seen on OP's Kenwood and the mating male SMA on the antenna. The Chinese brands instead used a male SMA on the HT and mating female on the antenna, which was confusingly and incorrectly called a reverse SMA by some hams because it was the "reverse" of the female-HT/male-antenna standard they were used to, which morphed into "Chinese HT's have RP-SMA." They do not.

Comment: I'll be darned, you're right.  Apparently I fell for the "reverse-SMA" mixup. No wonder I was still confused when looking at my chinese HTs.  Thanks for setting me right... I'll edit my answer.